# PostgreSQL slow WHERE clause in sparse join

Tags: sql, database, performance, postgresql, join

I am currently working on a project which will use a PostgreSQL database of (eventually) about 200 million rows in which two of the tables have an interesting relationship. Table A contains items with, among others, fields A.a, A.b and A.c while table B contains B.a, B.b, B.c and a value B.v for each of these. The objective here is to be able to join the tables A and B such that I can obtain the value B.v for each entry in A. I currently have B setup with B.a, B.b and B.c as a multi-column index with a unique property. This is the best way I could think of to represent this relationship (keeping in mind that table A might contain millions of rows while B will contain only 10,000). If there is a better way to store this, I would love to know.

To complicate matters, I also require some information from a third table C, which I also join into both A and B.

To illustrate the table structures:

```
                        Table "A"
    Column    |   Type   | Modifiers | Storage | Stats target | Description 
--------------+----------+-----------+---------+--------------+-------------
 id           | bigint   |           | plain   |              | 
 a            | boolean  | not null  | plain   |              | 
 b            | integer  |           | plain   |              | 
 c            | smallint |           | plain   |              | 
 user_id      | bigint   |           | plain   |              | 
Indexes:
    PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (id)
    btree (user_id)
    btree (a)
    btree (b)
    btree (c)

                                                Table "B"
    Column    |   Type   |                         Modifiers                          | Storage | Stats target | Description 
--------------+----------+------------------------------------------------------------+---------+--------------+-------------
 id           | integer  | not null default nextval('A_id_seq'::regclass)             | plain   |              | 
 a            | boolean  | not null                                                   | plain   |              | 
 b            | integer  | not null                                                   | plain   |              | 
 c            | smallint | not null                                                   | plain   |              | 
 v            | bigint   | not null                                                   | plain   |              | 
Indexes:
    PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (a, b, c)
    btree (c)
    btree (b)
    btree (b, c, a)
    btree (v)
Foreign-key constraints:
    ...

                                Table "C"
    Column    |           Type           | Modifiers | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
--------------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+--------------+-------------
 user_id      | bigint                   | not null  | plain    |              | 
 p            | integer                  |           | plain    |              | 
Indexes:
    PRIMARY KEY, btree (user_id)
    UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (user_id)
    btree (p)
```

The objective is then to find all rows in table A where the corresponding value in B is greater than 1000 and the value in C is greater than 100. Currently, my query for this is as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM A
    INNER JOIN B ON
        A.a = B.a AND
        A.b = B.b AND
        A.c = B.c
    LEFT JOIN C ON
        A.user_id = C.user_id
    WHERE C.p < 100 AND B.v > 1000
    LIMIT 100;
```

This is, however, very slow, taking several seconds to finish. Peculiarly, removing the B.v > 1000 contraint speeds up the query from about 6 seconds to only 20 milliseconds. I suspect that this is because entries with a B.v value over 1000 are very rare (about 20,000 in millions). I then used the EXPLAIN ANALYSE clause on the query to produce the following:

```
 Limit  (cost=0.00..1133.08 rows=100 width=215) (actual time=18.516..6571.243 rows=100 loops=1)
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..1940860.96 rows=171291 width=215) (actual time=18.513..6571.113 rows=100 loops=1)
         ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..1232018.65 rows=1171013 width=64) (actual time=9.293..6326.114 rows=3303 loops=1)
               ->  Seq Scan on A (cost=0.00..81726.86 rows=3888586 width=36) (actual time=0.018..857.948 rows=452207 loops=1)
               ->  Index Scan using [...] on B  (cost=0.00..0.28 rows=1 width=28) (actual time=0.010..0.010 rows=0 loops=452207)
                     Index Cond: (a = a AND b = b AND c = c)
                     Filter: (v > 1000)
         ->  Index Scan using user_id_pk on C  (cost=0.00..0.59 rows=1 width=151) (actual time=0.072..0.072 rows=0 loops=3303)
               Index Cond: (user_id = A.user_id)
               Filter: (p < 80)
 Total runtime: 6571.550 ms
```

It seems odd to me that it would take so much longer to add a single constraint to a query just because the number of matches to that constraint is small (as a sidenote, reducing it from 1000 to 10, which yields many more results, also provides a huge speedup).

So, my question is this: can the database server not use the index I applied to B.v in this query? Also, is it possible to speed up this query in any way?

Thank you for reading and please excuse me if I have made a very obvious mistake, but I haven't been able to find any solution to my problem so far.

**Edit:**
Execution plan without the B.v > 1000 clause:

```
 Limit  (cost=0.00..13278.28 rows=100 width=215) (actual time=76.185..237.820 rows=100 loops=1)
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..1383862.57 rows=10422 width=215) (actual time=76.183..237.739 rows=100 loops=1)
         ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..1322702.97 rows=71251 width=64) (actual time=18.270..121.272 rows=840 loops=1)
               ->  Seq Scan on A  (cost=0.00..85715.82 rows=4078382 width=36) (actual time=0.037..2.520 rows=1377 loops=1)
               ->  Index Scan using [...] on B  (cost=0.00..0.28 rows=1 width=28) (actual time=0.082..0.083 rows=1 loops=1377)
                     Index Cond: (a = a AND b = b AND c = c)
         ->  Index Scan using user_id_pk on C (cost=0.00..0.85 rows=1 width=151) (actual time=0.136..0.136 rows=0 loops=840)
               Index Cond: (user_id = A.user_id)
               Filter: (C.p < 80)
 Total runtime: 238.076 ms
```

Comment: Why a LEFT JOIN when the WHERE condition makes it an INNER JOIN? C isn't optional, LEFT JOIN doesn't make sense. Or move the WHERE condition on C.p to the LEFT JOIN condition when C results are optional: ON A.user_id = C.user_id AND C.p < 100.

Comment: 1) `left JOIN + where ...` is actually a plain join (what Frank says above) 2) you don't have statistics (estimated and actual costs differ) run; `VACUUM ANALYZE` on each table. 3) don't name your columns {a,b,c}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the predicate on B.v is very selective, then place an index on that column.

I suspect that the reason for the slowness with that predicate in place is that the query cannot be performed based only on accessing the unique index on B -- instead every row in the table needs to be accessed to check the value of v as well.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. However, as far as I can see, there is already a B-tree index on B.v. Is there something wrong with this index or is PostgreSQL not using it?

Comment: you'd best post both explain plans

Comment: I have added the execution plan without the B.v > 1000 clause.

Comment: Could you try adding v to the combined (b,c,a) index? Either add a new index or replace the existing one. That should make it only access the index.

Comment: Can you make sure that ANALYZE has been run on the table, and if that doesn't change anything I would try an index on (v, a, b, c). You could then drop the indexes on b and v